# Text editor that can search in multiple files for Linux

Tags: linux, gratis, text-editor

In Windows I used Notepad++ and its search function to look for a specific text in multiple files from a chosen folder.

In Ubuntu I use gEdit, but it has only basic search. Is there any gEdit plugin or standalone text editor that can search a text in the content of multiple files (plain text files)?

It should run on Linux and be freeware.

Comment: Related question: [text editor - Is there a gedit plugin that adds search features? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10873/is-there-a-gedit-plugin-that-adds-search-features)

Comment: Notepad++ works fairly well for me under Wine.

Comment: @user3693236, my Notepad++ doesn't search in Linux folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Here ya go: [Advanced find / replace plugin for gedit (Gnome Text Editor)](https://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/)

> Features:
>
> - Find / Replace in active document
> - Find / Replace in all opened documents
> - Find in all files in selected directory
> - Find / Replace in current selected text
> - Support regular expressions
> - Support multi-lines pattern
> - Highlight search results
> - Show results in bottom panel
> - Select and find next/previous
> - Multi-language support
> - Support both gedit2.x and 3.x **(Support for gedit2.x is terminated from 2013/03/31.)**

#### There's also another plugin: [Gedit File Search Plugin](https://oliver.github.io/gedit-file-search/) *(source code [here](https://github.com/oliver/gedit-file-search))*

> ```
> File Search Plugin for Gedit
> =============================
> This is a search plugin for Gedit to search for a text inside a directory.
>
> The plugin was tested with Gedit 3.4.1 under Ubuntu 12.04, and with Gedit 3.8.3 under
> Fedora 19. It should also work under other versions of Gedit 3.
>
> Note that Gedit 2 and older are not supported by this plugin any more
> (there is an old version of this plugin available, though, which supports Gedit 2).
> ```

Comment: How can I install it? In the original link of the plugin, the installation part is empty.

Answer (score 6):

[**Geany**](http://geany.org/) (Free/Open Source Software) is a lightweight text editor with some basic IDE features. I use it as my default text editor because I like that it’s so fast (especially the startup and opening big files).

It’s available cross-platform and typically included in distribution’s packages (for example, [in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/geany)).

With <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> you can open a search window (sorry, my screenshots are in German):

[image: Geany: screenshot of search window]

You can enter a search string ("foo" in the screenshot) and define the path for which folder should be searched ("/home/unor" in the screenshot).

You can enable searching in sub-folders. You can also filter for which file types should be searched. It supports regular expressions and you can enable case sensitivity.

It uses [**grep**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for searching. In the last text field you can enter additional arguments for grep.

The search results are shown in a log window at the bottom:

[image: Geany: screenshot of search results]

It shows the file name (and relative path), the line number where the string was found and it displays this line. Right-clicking a result allows to copy all these infos into the clipboard. Double-clicking a result opens the document in a tab in Geany.

As you can see in the screenshot, it lists the same document for each line the string was found.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for that - I have only used the Windows version but it has a Linux version. Sublime Text is not free; it does have an unlimited trial though so you can try it out for as long as you need to decide.

It's search/replace functionality is almost the same as Notepad++ although the interface is moderately different. To acces it just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for find in files or you can go through the find menu. It has regex or normal search/replace as well as case sensitive option.

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs, I do `M-x grep` for this task.

Then I can browse the list of found occurences through an Emacs interface (and with `M-g n`, `M-g p` for next and previous).